# Author ID mismatch from database

Tags: database

The author->ID for one particular author is returning a different value than what exists in the database.
The database has the author's id as 2, but when I query author->ID, it returns the value 11.
So, if I try to use the author's id for any purpose, I get the wrong results. Other functions related to this author work fine.

For all other authors, everything works absolutely fine.

I am using the coauthors plus plugin.

```
foreach ( $coauthors as $coauthor ) {
$id = $coauthor->ID;
// some code to fetch author details using $id
}
```

Here the $id that I get is 11, though it should be 2. For all other authors, I get the right results.

And when I add this author to a post, even at that time the dropdown(in the field that coauthor plugin uses to add authors) shows the id as 11.

This is what I get with var_dump($coauthors);

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#318 (14) { 
    ["ID"]=> string(2) "11" 
    ["display_name"]=> string(4) "User1" 
    ["first_name"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["last_name"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["user_login"]=> string(4) "user1" 
    ["user_email"]=> string(17) "email@gmail.com" 
    ["website"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["aim"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["yahooim"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["jabber"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["user_nicename"]=> string(4) "user1" 
    ["type"]=> string(12) "guest-author" 
}
```

Here all values except the ID are correct.

I could go ahead and delete this particular user and create a new one. But I have to be sure that it won't happen again. So I am trying to understand what could have caused this.

I know this is a very vague question but any help would be great.

Comment: You will need to post your code if you want answers that are not just wild guesses. There must be something happening to break this-- plugin, theme, filter, something. Please add all the detail you have.

Comment: hi @s_ha_dum i added a few more details .. maybe these might help in figuring out what went wrong ..

Comment: Put `var_dump($coauthors);` just above that `foreach` and post the output.

Comment: Your plugin is only listing the one author. That is a plugin problem it seems to me. Honestly, that makes the question off-topic.

Comment: in this case there was only one author .. else i get array(2), array(3) and so on with the details of all users given by [0], [1] and so on .. for all other authors the ID returned is correct ..

Comment: It is nonetheless a plugin problem. Your plugin has not set the ID correctly. I don't know why and without installing and debugging the plugin I can't know. Have you checked the plugin's support?